# Why is Jquery not seeing the unique id?

Tags: jquery

I have a page that contains dynamic forms and tables that are fetched with ajax. I am trying to target each table depending on which form submit button was pressed but for some reason jquery does not seem to see the unique id of the tables. I suspect that jquery is only fetching the id of  the first table but I can't understand why?

`console.log(tableid)` prints `myTable1` on all the submit buttons I press however inspecting the html on the page shows me that all the id's of `myTable` are unique eg `myTable1,myTable2,myTable3`.....and so on.

The dynamic form and table

```
<form id="myForm" class="myForm" action="" method="post" style="">

    <input type="hidden" name="page_id" value="'.$id.'">


   <button type="submit" class="fabutton"></i></button>
</form> <!--END OF FORM---->



<table id="myTable'.$i.'" class="table"><!--$i increments by 1 with each form---->
    <tbody>
        <tr>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The jquery (on another page where the form and table are rendered)

```
$(document).on('submit', '.myForm', '.results', function(e) {

             var tableid = $('.table').attr('id'); //Get table id

             console.log(tableid)
```

Comment: Would be more useful to see the **rendered** HTML, rather than your dynamic code.

Comment: Also - your form doesn't contain the table, so how would it know which table to look at? Your jQuery just says "find the first table and get the id".  And it does..  Which table SHOULD it get?

Comment: $('.table') would return array of elements ,so when you are tyring to get id ,it is returning first elements id

Comment: If you call [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) on a selector that selects many elements it will return the attribute value of the first. From jQuery: *"Get the value of an attribute for the **first element** in the set of matched elements or set one or more attributes for every matched element."*.

Comment: Your event handler **does not** work on both classes, you have the wrong arguments

Answer (score 2):

That is because you do `var tableid = $('.table').attr('id');`

This is not limited to the current form you are working with but to the whole document.

**Update**

If the `.table` is directly following the form element then do

```
var tableid = $(this).next();
```

---

**Original** (*will not work because `.table` is not inside the form*)

Try using a context when looking for the table, like the following (*`this` points to the form, so it will look for a `.table` in that form*)

```
var tableid = $('.table', this).attr('id');
```

Comment: Or: `$(this).next('.table')` to be sure.

Comment: I have in fact tried $(this).next('.table') but it didn't work. The variable remains undefined. I should add that var myform=$(this).attr('id'); shows me all the unique form id's as I would expect.

Comment: In the end this was the answer: var tableid=$(this).closest("div").find("table").attr("id");//find table id